# Php within javascript : Not working

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script>
document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML="<?php echo 'foo bar'; ?>";
</script> 
<div id="comment"></div>
```

This should give the word "foo bar" in the div element,but its not.Do not know where i'm going wrong. Please help.

Comment: i do not know about this, but probably the php withing the quotes will get included in the HTML and not parsed. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `comment` element :

```
document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML="...";
```

Before it is declared :

```
<div id="comment"></div>
```

And firebug shows the following error :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/so-6805710.png))</sub>

You should :

- First, create the element in your HTLM
- And, only after, use it :

  - Either by changing the order you are doing things in your code,
  - Or waiting until the HTML page is fully loaded to execute Javascript.

If you choose the first solution, your code will look like this :

```
<div id="comment"></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML="<?php echo 'foo bar'; ?>";
</script>
```

And it will work :

- The `foo bar` string will be visile
- And there won't be any JS error anymore.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/so-6805710-2.png))</sub>

Comment: Working.Thanks.had Forgotten abt the dom model.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I'll take that as a compliment :-p

Answer (score 1):

The script needs to go below the div, as it's trying to populate a div that hasn't been inserted into the DOM yet.

Comment: had Forgotten abt the dom model.Changed it.Now,working.Thanks